# Using serial for android library

Tags: android, usbserial, ftdi

I'm trying to implement this https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/master/UsbSerialExamples/src/com/hoho/android/usbserial/examples/SerialConsoleActivity.java in my project but there is something wrong with this sample.

Line 121:

```
 sDriver.setParameters(115200, 8, UsbSerialDriver.STOPBITS_1, UsbSerialDriver.PARITY_NONE);
```

Why I can't see this method setParameters()?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I tried to use the example project. The problem I had was that I was using usb-serial-for-android-v010.jar that you can download from the git repository. I think it was created using an older version of the project and doesn't support some of the newer features like setParameters. If you downloaded the example project there should be a folder inside called UsbSerialLibrary. Import that into your IDE and add it to your build path: (Eclipse) **Properties>Java Build Path>Projects>Add**. This should let you use setParameters.

Also, the API was recently refactored so you may want to look at that.